# laravel foreach select option and required

Tags: javascript, laravel, required, select-options

Now I do foreach the select option and do the required but when I foreach it only required the top option, the rest refuse required. How do I requried every option?

blade:

```
              @foreach($student as $index => $students)

               <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="student_id[]" value="{{$students->student_id}}">
               <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="member_id" value="{{CurrentUser::user()->member_id}}">

               <select name="status[]" class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="status" required>
                <option disabled selected value="" >
                 Choose...
                </option>
                <option name="status[]" value="Present">Present</option>
                <option name="status[]" value="Absent">Absent</option>
                <option name="status[]" value="Tardy">Tardy</option>
               </select><br>
                <p style="color:#D30707;font-size:5px;" id="check_status"></p>

              @endforeach
```

js:

```
              function myFunction() {

               var status = document.getElementById("status");

                if (!status.checkValidity()) {
                 document.getElementById("check_status").innerHTML = "Please choose status field.";
                } else {
                 document.getElementById("check_status").innerHTML = "";
                } 

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do foreach in blade you should generate unique ids for each of your input or element you want to select later using JavaScript. Now you have situation that you have generate N number of inputs with id="status" so your JavaScript code will select only first one.

You could instead of unique ids add some dummy class to your element and then select with JS all elements containing that class and loop trough them to check is required satisfied.

Comment: If I were to call a class instead, what do I have to change here?  var status = document.getElementById("status");

Comment: var statuses = document.getElementsByClassName("status"); This will return array of elements. Then you have to loop trough this using JavaScript and check your condition for each of element.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<select name="status[]" class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="status" onchange="myFunction()" multiple required>
  <option disabled selected value="" >
  Choose...
  </option>
  <option name="status[]" value="Present">Present</option>
  <option name="status[]" value="Absent">Absent</option>
  <option name="status[]" value="Tardy">Tardy</option>
</select>
<br>
<p style="color:#D30707;font-size:5px;" id="check_status"></p>
```

in js

```js
function myFunction() {

  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var selectedValues = Array.from(status.selectedOptions).map(option => option.value);
  if (!selectedValues.includes('Absent')) { // change here containe value
      document.getElementById("check_status").innerHTML = "Please choose status field.";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("check_status").innerHTML = "";
  } 
}
```